# Why does QApplication give memory leaks?

Tags: c++, qt, valgrind, qtgui, qapplication

I have a simple code:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it in Qt Creator using pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = testLeaks
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS  +=

FORMS    +=
```

Command `valgrind ./testLeaks` says about leaks and prints the following:

```
==31276== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31276==     in use at exit: 1,190,544 bytes in 7,267 blocks
==31276==   total heap usage: 46,096 allocs, 38,829 frees, 6,716,079 bytes allocated
==31276== 
==31276== LEAK SUMMARY:
==31276==    definitely lost: 2,788 bytes in 11 blocks
==31276==    indirectly lost: 7,065 bytes in 182 blocks
==31276==      possibly lost: 318,238 bytes in 1,233 blocks
==31276==    still reachable: 862,453 bytes in 5,841 blocks
==31276==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

If I comment QApplication, there are no leaks. Why does this class give leaks?

Comment: qt 5.2.0 and qt creator 3.0.0

Comment: Same, here but I am getting: ==3005== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2). I think you skipped that part. By the way, I do not think 320KB+ "possible" loss is that bad, and it may even be coming from some underlying dependency. I guess this would need a more thorough introspection, preferably with some static analyzer run. :) Also, it is better to use `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all -v ./testLeaks`

Comment: I haven't used valgrind but at least from my work in finding leaks in Qt on Windows - there are lots of static objects in Qt so if the memory snapshot is taken before they are destroyed that memory could come up as leaks.

Comment: I wanted to post here what --leak-check=full had shown, but it had shown to many text and therefore I decided not to post it here. Actually at start valgrind says about some problems in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so. It has begun since I updated libc6 to 2.17. May it be the reason of this leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the following command provides more information:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all -v ./testLeaks
```

Also, you cut out the end of the short output:

```
==3005== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2).
```

Either way, it is very likely that it is not a bug in QApplication itself, but some underlying dependency, especially you mentioned that it would happen after a `libc` update.

I have had several problems with `libc` and other low-level library where you would think they do not leak memory, and you are surprised in the end of the day.

This could be easily checked by writing an example using that library.

However, since it is just about 320K+ and Qt applications (especially GUI) will require a lot more, I would not consider this as a non-negligible amount.

Comment: ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)